# How to decrement several variables in C++in a single line statement?

Tags: c++, variables, decrement

**Edit: I replaced the phrase 'in one line' by 'in a single line statement' since this is what I was looking for**

Let's say we have the following variables at hand:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 9;
```

Is there a way to compress this ...

```
a--;
b--;
```

... into in a single line statement??
The question is not about decrementing multiple variables in a for loop,
since this seems to be a common yet unrelated question.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: I hope you don't think that less code is better code.

Comment: You can always just put the two statements in the same line: `a--;b--;`.

Comment: @Aziz I was just curious :)

Comment: @Diggi55: The reason I'm asking is because this may lead to less-readable code. It is always better to keep the code as clear as possible, even if it means few extra lines of code.

Comment: ^^^ what the others say.  When you get to line-by-line debugging, you will rapidly find out why skilled and experienced developers hate 'clever' code:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably mean "in a single statement", not just "in a single line".
Then you can use the comma-operator:

```
(a--,b--);
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a single line statement ... I didn't know this word till now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

```
// use a template
template<class ... Args>
void decr(Args& ... args){
    (... , --args);
}

decr(a,b,c);

// or, in C++20, auto
void decr(auto& ... args){
    (... , --args);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just write the statements in one single line, like this :

```
a--, b--;
```

(thanks to @Aziz for the improvement with the comma instead of the semicolon)

Comment: similarly, you can use a comma to separate them: `a--,b--;`

Answer (score 1):

You can do like :

```
int a = 5;
int b = 4;
(a -= 1), (b -= 1);
std::cout << a << b;
```

Output: 43

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    main ()
    {
      int a = 5, b = 9;
      a--, b--;
      cout << a;
      cout << b;        
      return 0;
    }
```

Output:
48